# How to see the set options to a select2 instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I want to get the options set to a select2 instance, in specific if the allowClear option is set to true or false.
Navigating through the object I found the allowClear option in

> **jQuery... -> select2 -> options -> options,**

but I don't know how to access to it via code.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to list all of the options set to a select2 instance

```
$(selector).data('select2').options.options
```

I needed the allowClear option so the answer to my question would be this

```
$element.data('select2').options.options.allowClear
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access it like this

```
yourObjectName.jQuery(those after number).select2.options.options.allowClear
```

Comment: That number changes constantly, so... it's not a viable way to access to the property.

Comment: why are you saving those number after it

Comment: if you are changing it are you saving those numbers in a variable

Comment: I'm not changing it, it's auto-generated by the select2 plugin

Comment: do you have access to that jquery name and those numbers

Comment: No, If I had that I wouldn't have asked this question, it would be as easy as you posted in your answer.